# Dynamic generation of row column and header

Tags: java, html, database, jsp, html-table

I need to code a table in which row and column, and headers are dynamic. Previously I was hard coding the table in HTML and headers display tag for displaying details from Database. Now since column, and headers are also varying as per different requirement in my project I needed to do everything dynamic. Any suggestions on what to use would be appreciated.

So this is how I was doing it earlier:

```
 <TABLE BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <TR>
                <TH>Header1</TH>
                <TH>Header2</TH>
                <TH>Header3</TH>
                <TH>Header4</TH>
            </TR>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${value.getHeader1().size() - 1}">
                <TR>
                    <TD>
                            ${value.getHeader1().get(i)}
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                            ${value.getHeader2().get(i)}
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                            ${value.getHeader3().get(i)}
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                            ${value.getHeader4().get(i)}
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </c:forEach>
        </TABLE>
```

From the above `<table>` schema, the header is hard coded. Now I needed to make it dynamic and based on any particular requirement and selection my servlet will query and pass results in such dynamically behavior table.

Any help on this would be really really helpful and great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get your `headers` array from `value` variable.

-For header iteration, you can get first header object from array

-For value iteration, do a for loop for each header object

```
<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="1" style="text-align: center;">
   <TR>
      <c:forEach var="h" items="${value.getHeaders.get(0)}">
         <TH>${h.title}</TH>
      </c:forEach>
   </TR>
   <c:forEach var="headers" items="${value.getHeaders()}">
      <TR>
         <c:forEach var="header" items="${headers.getHeader}">
            <TD>${header.value}</TD>
         </c:forEach>
      </TR>
   </c:forEach>
</TABLE>
```